# Regex matching order numbers e.g DE + 10 numbers or AT +10 numbers

Tags: regex, numbers, chars

I'm actually trying to match some order numbers in a string.

The string could look like this:

```
SDSFwsfcwqrewrPL0000018604ergerzergdsfa
```

or

```
FwsfcwqrewrAT0000018604ergerzergdsfaD
```

and I need to match the "PL0000018604" or "AT0000018604".

Actually I'm using something like that and it works:

```
.?(AT[0-9]{10})|(BE[0-9]{10})|(FR[0-9]{10})|(IT[0-9]{10})
```

But the more order prefixes we get, the longer the expression will be.
It is always 2 uppercase chars followed by 10 digits and I want to specify the different uppercase chars.

Is there any shorter version?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: `/[A-Z]{2}\d{10}/` Or yet `/[A-Z]{2}\d{10,n}/` where n the most digits in sequence

Comment: That one I already used but there are no chars specific so the match could be any 2 upper chars followed by 10 digits.
Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the prefixes must be specific, there's not much of a way to make the pattern shorter. Though, you can collect all the prefixes at the front of the expression so you only have to have the numeric part once.

for example:

```
(AT|BE|FR|IT)[0-9]{10}
```

Depending on how you call it, if you need the whole expression to be captured as a group (versus simply *matching*, which is what the question asked about), you can add parenthesis around the whole expression. That doesn't change what is matched, but it will change what is returned by whatever function uses the expression.

```
((AT|BE|FR|IT)[0-9]{10})
```

And, of course, if you just want the number part to also be captured as a separate group, you can add more parenthesis

```
((AT|BE|FR|IT)([0-9]{10}))
```

Comment: Thanks, I already tried that and the match will be "PL" or "AT"

Comment: @DeeKaay: I don't understand your comment. If you want to match PL, add it to the list  `(AT|PL|...)`

Comment: Your expression will not match "AT0000018604" it will only match "AT"

Comment: @DeeKaay: no, it will match AT followed by 10 digits. The pattern says "match one of AT, BE, FR or IT, followed by exactly 10 characters in the range 0-9"

Comment: well it will match only AT because of mathing group of 1 if used in .net framework. If used whole match it is at index 0

Comment: Yes it will but the return value will only be AT but I need AT and the 10 digits. not the complete line :)

Comment: `(AT|BE|FR|IT)([0-9]{10})` Try this and look at index + 1, which should have the other group in brackets

Comment: @IgorisAzanovas: matching group zero will match the AT part. The question didn't mention anything about matching groups, and mentioned nothing about .net. It only asked about a pattern that matches a particular type of string. If you need a matching group, just add one. I've updated my answer to include that.

Comment: I'm not using .net, it's for php.
Thanks I will try it :)